# Opening another app with React Ionic on IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-native, capacitor, ionic-react

I have a problem with opening another app with React Ionic on IOS using Capacitor. **canOpenUrl** always returns true, even when the app (bankid) is not installed. When I run **openUrl** nothing happens.

```
//First i import capacitor
import {Capacitor} from '@capacitor/core';

const Login: React.FC = () => {
  const openBankID = async () => {
    const iosURL = 'bankid://app.bankid.com/?autostarttoken=${token}&redirect=app://'

    const res = await Capacitor.Plugins?.App.canOpenUrl({ url: iosURL });
    if (res != undefined) {
      await Capacitor.Plugins?.App.openUrl({ url: iosURL })

    } else {
      alert("Can't open the application");
    }

  }

  return (
    <IonPage className="LoginPage">
      <IonContent fullscreen className="LoginPage">
       <IonCol size="12">
                <IonButton
                  onClick={() => {
                    openBankID();


                  }} expand="block" disabled={false}>
                  Logga in med BankID
          </IonButton>
              </IonCol>

      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
   );
};

export default Login;

)
```

I've also added the app I'm to open in info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>bankid</string>
            <string>bankid://</string>
            <string>bankid://*</string>
        </array>
```

Answer (score 0):

The constant `res` will always be an object so it won't be `undefined`. From [the docs](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/app#canopenurl), the signature of `canOpenUrl` is:

`canOpenUrl(options: { url: string; }) => Promise<{ value: boolean; }>`

If you amend your condition from `if (res != undefined)` to `if (res.value === true)`, it should work.